# JavaScript scrollTop problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Long story short, I need to get the total scroll size for a text area, in a unit scrollTop can relate to, but I have no idea how.

scrollHeight, this, that and everything else seemed to be no help. Any suggestions would be appreciated, but for reference, it needs to be able to set a text area of variable size and length's scroll bar to be exactly in the middle.

Also, I'm using chrome 12 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you :

```
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - (element.clientHeight / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$('#foo').scrollTop($('#foo')[0].scrollHeight / 2);
```

And a demo thing: http://jsfiddle.net/Rgyk4/8/.

Comment: That only seems to work based on the relative location on the page. At least it doesn't work for me for that which I am doing. (unless Jquery is compensating for something)